# Error while referencing into a global variable using multiple files

Tags: c, header, global-variables, extern

These are my code files:

#### header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
extern int bar;
#endif
```

#### foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

void foo(void) {
    printf("foo: bar = %d\n", bar);
    printf("foo: ++bar = %d\n", ++bar);
}
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int main(void) {
    int bar=0;

    printf("main: bar = %d\n", bar);
    printf("main: ++bar = %d\n", bar);

    foo();

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile those in Ubuntu:

```
gcc -c foo.c
gcc main.c foo.o -o program
```

I get this error from the linker:

```
/tmp/ccWHhwtm.o: In function `foo':
foo.c:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `bar'
foo.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `bar'
foo.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `bar'
foo.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `bar'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I have seen from other answered questions here, in order to share a global variable to multiple files, you will just have to declare the variable in the header file using `extern` keyword and define it in one of the **.c** codes.
That is what I have done here, but I get this error.

What is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bar` should be defined in file scope:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

int bar=0;

int main(void) {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>When I was typing: "What is happening", just then, ironically, I figured out the answer :-P.</strike>

The problem is that I define the variable inside `main` function. Thus the definition scope is limited between the braces.